# Can't get logging to work in Spring boot 1.2.5.RELEASE

Tags: logging, spring-boot, slf4j, logback, spring-data-neo4j

1. I am using spring boot 1.2.5.RELEASE. I have added logging.file to my application.properties. I have printed out LOG_PATH env variable and it shows the appropriate log file, but still there is not log file. I am using the spring boot default logger logback with slf4j. The only way it would work is to put a logback.xml in classpath. The documentation unfortunately doesn't say so.
2. I am using spring-data-neo4j 4.0.0.RELEASE. I updated to Spring Boot 1.3.0.M5 to see if the logging issue had been fixed. Before I could test that, another problem appeared, now spring boot is forcing spring-data-3.4.2.RELEASE. I could not exclude that in any way.

Both of these are issues, which I hope someone in the spring data team notices.

Comment: post some configuration. For overriding versions you should simply add the version of the Spring Data release you want to use. Spring Boot 1.3.0.M5 uses the latest [`Gosling-RELEASE`](http://spring.io/blog/2015/09/01/spring-data-release-train-gosling-goes-ga). If you want Spring Data neo4j for a different version, then simply include the dependency with the version you want to use. (All of this assumes the use of the Spring Boot starter parent as parent project in your maven pom!).

Comment: Also what is the variable `LOG_FILE` pointing to? This should be a system (JDK) variable not an environment variable ...

Comment: I have done that. I added the spring-data-4.0.0.RELEASE in my gradle dependency but compilation fails if I change to 1.3.0.M5. This is because of the older version of spring-data-neo4j being compiled. I also tried exclusion in gradle, that also doesn't work.

Comment: Ah gradle, didn't catch that. Ordering of the dependencies can be important... Not sure how to override in maven.

Comment: Both LOG_FILE & LOG_PATH points to the correct path that I had given in application.properties. I had given a relative path to either one, I had also created a directory, but nothing helped. That is why I thought to start using 1.3.0.M5.

Comment: Have you tried using logback *without* slf4j ? I am asking, because I have similar setup with 1.2.5.RELEASE and logging to logging.file *is* working for me - but I am not using slf4j.

Comment: Guys, sorry for my late response, apparently a logback.xml is mandatory for logback to work. Once I created the logback.xml at put it in the class path it works liek a charm.